# Removing missing rows and duplicate row using dplyr in R data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Let the data frame is

```
data<-data.frame(name=c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "D"), num = c(1,NA, 0,NA, 1, NA, 0))
```

I got result:

```
name num

1    A   1
2    B  NA
3    A   0
4    C  NA
5    A   1
6    B  NA
7    D   0
```

I want to use dplyr to remove the duplicates row from column1(name) and remove the "NA" rows from the column2(num) in single pipe function.

I want to have my answer like

```
    name num

1    A   1
7    D   0
```

How many rows will be there in a dataframe from which missing values in "num" column have been eliminated and duplicated values in ‘name’ column have been eliminated.

Any suggestion using pipe function.

Comment: Have you tried `filter` and `distinct`?

Comment: On what basis you decided to drop the 3rd row? A 0

Comment: The 3rd row under column (name) "A" is duplicate character vector to 1st row. so I want to remove 3rd row.

Comment: How many rows will be there in a dataframe from which missing values in  "num" column have been eliminated and duplicated values in ‘name’ column have been eliminated.

Comment: When I write the code data%>%filter(!is.na(num))%>%filter(!duplicated(name)). I got the my answer. Thank you.                                                                                                
     name num
1    A   1
2    D   0

Answer (score 3):

try

```
library(dplyr) 

data
  distinct() %>%
  filter(!is.na(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 library(dplyr)
 na.omit(data) %>% unique()
```

which returns this:

```
  name num
1    A   1
3    A   0
7    D   0
```

It is not clear to me on what basis you decided to drop the 3rd row in your desired output.